# Request WindowPlacement in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am currently writing a Web Application, which reads the screen setup of the desktop application.

To do this I am using:

```
navigator.permissions.query({
    name: "window-placement"
});
```

Unfortunately I do not get notified by chrome, that the permission got requested.
I wonder if this is only to get the current state, but not really requesting permission?

I get the hint by Chrome if I use

```
window.getScreenDetails()
    .then(sd => {... do something with Screendetials})
    .catch(e => {... do something if not granted})
```

I would prefer to ask for permission and then read the screendetails.

What is the best way to solve this?